# Could a gravitational lens in the far future be used to detect 20th century radio or television broadcasts?

Tags: far-future, radio

Wondering if a naturally occurring gravitational lens (such as one created by a star or black hole) could be used in the future by someone searching for "ancient" (ie, our recent) radio and TV emissions. Might that be a way of reducing the inverse-square law's effect on those signals? I know there have been proposals to use the Sun as a gravitational lens to detect alien microwave transmissions. I'm wondering if, by analogy, one could use the same technique to find human broadcasts, many years in the future.

Comment: Do you mean some distant aliens listening to our broadcasts, or somehow bending the waves to go back to Earth?

Answer (score 2):

This scheme was mooted on the Halfbakery some time back.

http://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Gravity_20Time_20Mirror#1102098287

> Gravity Time Mirror:  Seeing our past using the sling-shot effect of a
>   black hole's gravitational pull on light.    Using a very powerful
>   telescope, we could look right at the very edge of a black hole where
>   a light path made it 180degrees around the black hole due to the
>   slingshot effect of gravitation. If the black hole were, say, 1000
>   light years distance from us, we would be looking back at ourselves
>   2000 years ago, a gravitational mirror to the past.
>
> — BruceRH90, Dec 03 2004

Pretty slick idea.  I think it would work better with radio (as you propose) than with visible light.